# Using variable as delimiter for zsh `j:<delimiter>:` parameter expansion flag

Tags: shell-script, zsh

How can I use the value of a variable as the value for the delimiter string for the zsh `j:<delimiter>:` parameter expansion flag?

If I cannot do that, what is the most efficient & concise way to use a variable to delimit values in zsh?

```bsh
array=(a b)
delimiter=,
printf -- "%s" ${(j:,:)array}          # good: outputs: a,b
printf -- "%s" ${(j:$delimiter:)array} # bad:  outputs: a$delimiterb
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the `p` parameter expansion flag:

```
printf %s ${(pj:$delimiter:)array}
```

Quoting the doc (emphasis mine):

> `p`
>
> Recognize the same escape sequences as the print builtin in string
>        arguments to any of the flags described below that follow this
>        argument.
>
> Alternatively, **with this option string arguments may be in the form
>        `$VAR` in which case the value of the variable is substituted**.  Note
>        this form is strict; the string argument does not undergo general
>        parameter expansion.

Comment: Thank you for this! I've reading through the zsh expansion docs a couple times trying to figure this out and somehow I always glazed right over this `p` flag.  Cheers!